# Why are people closing my question?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close

Since no one left a comment, can you tell me why would you think people are closing [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4775708/is-there-a-blog-engine-platform-that-can-display-revision-history), "**Is there a blog engine/platform that can display revision history?**". I'm just surprised, for I don't see any lack of legitimacy.

Comment: Present tense no longer

Comment: Migrated it to webapps for ya.

Comment: @Will Thanks. I went ahead and deleted it, because I had already asked there... yesterday.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Um... it's a bit on the broad side?

If you're looking for an installable product, you need to add *some* metrics - programming language, platform.... If you're looking for a hosted web app, it's more suitable for `webapps.SE`.

Comment: You may be right, but how should a newbie know about webapps.SE at all? Shouldn't the question be moved instead???

Answer (score 1):

It's not a programming problem or about a software algorithm or about a software tool **used for programming** or a programming unique matter, as per the FAQ:

> Stack Overflow is for professional and
> enthusiast programmers, people who
> write code because they love it. We
> feel the best Stack Overflow questions
> have a bit of source code in them, but
> if your question generally covers …
>
> - a specific programming problem
> - a software algorithm
> - software tools commonly used by programmers
> - matters that are unique to the programming
>
>   … then you’re in the right place to ask your question!

Your question was probably more appropriate for Meta or Webapps.

Comment: It's not appropriate for Meta because it has nothing to do with SO.

Comment: @CanSpice, actually if you read the question he wants it to see revision history on SO/SE.

Comment: It could read two ways. He could want a blogging solution that can view revision history on SO/SE, or he could want a blogging solution that offers revision history for entries on that blog (similar to the revision history SO/SE has). Given the title of his question, if he wanted the former he probably would have mentioned SO/SE in the title.

Comment: @can It's the latter.