# How do you figure out why people are voting to close your question?

Tags: feature-request, close-reasons

Sometimes I just don't understand why people are voting to close my question, which I took time and effort to clarify the knowns and the unknowns in my situation.

But what I saw is just some icy `close(2)`, which is rather disappointing.

I saw other people also asking ["Why are people closing my question?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76588/why-are-people-closing-my-question).

Wouldn't it be better if a reason must be given to close a question? Maybe a questioner can edit to improve his/her question?

Comment: Click on the button and look at the numbers next to each close reason? You don't have to actually submit a vote to close once you open that dialog. Or are those reasons not satisfying enough?

Comment: @animuson oh, I thought by clicking the `close` link I'm going to close my own question, never thought I could find reason counters inside. Thx.